# Programmatically Import Block Into AutoCAD (C#)

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for AutoCAD and want to import all the blocks it will use at the beginning to make sure that they are available when needed. To do that, I use this method

```
public static void ImportBlocks(string[] filesToTryToImport, string filter = "")
{
    foreach (string blockToImport in filesToTryToImport)
    {
        if (blockToImport.Contains(filter))
        {
            Database sourceDb = new Database(false, true); //Temporary database to hold data for block we want to import
            try
            {
                sourceDb.ReadDwgFile(blockToImport, System.IO.FileShare.Read, true, ""); //Read the DWG into a side database
                ObjectIdCollection blockIds = new ObjectIdCollection(); // Create a variable to store the list of block identifiers

                Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.TransactionManager tm = sourceDb.TransactionManager;

                using (Transaction myT = tm.StartTransaction())
                {
                    // Open the block table
                    BlockTable bt = (BlockTable)tm.GetObject(sourceDb.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead, false);

                    // Check each block in the block table
                    foreach (ObjectId btrId in bt)
                    {
                        BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)tm.GetObject(btrId, OpenMode.ForRead, false);
                        // Only add named & non-layout blocks to the copy list
                        if (!btr.IsAnonymous && !btr.IsLayout)
                        {
                            blockIds.Add(btrId);
                        }
                        btr.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                // Copy blocks from source to destination database
                IdMapping mapping = new IdMapping();
                sourceDb.WblockCloneObjects(blockIds, _database.BlockTableId, mapping, DuplicateRecordCloning.Replace, false);
                _editor.WriteMessage("\nCopied " + blockIds.Count.ToString() + " block definitions from " + blockToImport + " to the current drawing.");
            }
            catch (Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception ex)
            {
                _editor.WriteMessage("\nError during copy: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                sourceDb.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That method appears to work because it successfully executes. However when I go to insert a block in the drawing via AutoCAD's interface it doesn't show up as an option and when I try to insert it programmatically it throws a FileNotFound exception meaning it didn't work. What's wrong with this method? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is a less complicated method with a test method

```
public static void ImportSingleBlock(string fileToTryToImport)
{
    using (Transaction tr = _database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {
        Database sourceDb = new Database(false, true); //Temporary database to hold data for block we want to import
        try
        {
            sourceDb.ReadDwgFile(fileToTryToImport, System.IO.FileShare.Read, true, ""); //Read the DWG into a side database
            _database.Insert(fileToTryToImport, sourceDb, false);
            _editor.WriteMessage("\nSUCCESS: " + fileToTryToImport);
        }
        catch (Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception ex)
        {
            _editor.WriteMessage("\nERROR: " + fileToTryToImport);
        }
        finally
        {
            sourceDb.Dispose();
        }
        tr.Commit();
    }
}

[CommandMethod("TESTSINGLEBLOCKIMPORTING")]
public void TestSingleBlockImporting()
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) //Ending method on cancel
    {
        return;
    }
    string fileToTryToImport = ofd.FileName;
    using (Transaction tr = _database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {
        EntityMethods.ImportSingleBlock(fileToTryToImport);
        tr.Commit();
    }
}
```

[This file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwMHXVXHuDjaVZ4NUlNbHNUN0E/view?usp=sharing) is the block I'm trying to import. Hope this inspires someone cause I am desperately lost right now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct and should work. In fact I did tried it and works fine. You're probably missing to Commit() a outer transaction (where you call this ImportBlocs() method). Check:

```
using (Transaction trans = _database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
  ImportBlocks(... parameters here ...);
  trans.Commit(); // remember to call this commit, if omitted, Abort() is assumed
}
```

Comment: Didn't fix it for me...here is the block I'm trying to import, maybe the issue is with the block https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwMHXVXHuDjaVZ4NUlNbHNUN0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ah ok, this drawing "is" a block (and does not "contain" a block). Your original code is reading all block, but your drawing doesn't contain any. For drawings like this, you should call Database.Insert() passing the .dwg path, which will return the ObjectId of the new block definition that you can then use to create BlockReference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, very similar code. Issue was that

`_database.Insert(fileToTryToImport, sourceDb, false);`

should be

`_database.Insert(blockName, sourceDb, false);`

You can see that the first parameter has to be "blockName", and not the file path.